# Use a dialog to display a picture

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

What I am trying to do is displaying a thumbnail, and when you click on it the picture shows at full size (inside a dialog).

All I can get is either a picture that doesn't fit in the dialog, or a dialog that is wider than the picture.

Any ideas on how to achieve that ?

The current result without style (you see the elevators on the sides) :

[image]

**EDIT** the code for the dialog :

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Picture" class="dialog-picture">
    <md-dialog-content>
        <div>
            <img src="images/random.jpg" alt="image at full size">
        </div>
    </md-dialog-content>
</md-dialog>
```

**EDIT** with the property `max-width` set on :

[image]

**EDIT** : So far i got this : [image]

I changed the dialog style by deleting its max-height value (scss):

```
.dialog-picture {
    max-height: none;
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: `img {max-width: 100% }` ?

Comment: when I do that, the picture style overflows on the bottom, letting an elevator on the right side

Comment: Please provide ***some*** amount of code to go on.  You don't expect us to code a custom solution do you?  It's much easier to provide solutions for existing code.

Comment: I was just doing it, sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto; 
}
```

Comment: This code does the same as `max-width: 100%`, that is showing an elevator on the right side

Comment: put a overflow: hidden at the img container?

Comment: well then, the picture isn't fully displayed, it's cropped

Comment: well then your container probably has no boundaries?  do you have a width for the container?

Comment: for dialog-picture, have a position relative perhaps.

Comment: I added my code and a result for you in the question. And it is a angular material container, its position is relative, with a `max-width` of 80% (and max-height too)

Comment: changed the answer

Comment: That's it ! can you explain briefly your answer so that I understand ? Thank you anyway !

Comment: I think if you image is not a block element the least, css can't really know how to measure its width and height.

Answer (score -1):

Tried this ?

```
 img {max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }
```

Comment: img {max-width: auto; max-height: 100%; }

Comment: This time, the picture goes back to its original state, which is 2 elevators. I maybe have found a solution, which is styling the dialog instead of the picture